# Installing an app to run from an external HD

Tags: macos, adobe, library

I need to install an Adobe Air application on an external hard drive (the app puts a **lot** of data in local storage "/Users/$User/Library/Preferences/", and all this data only fits on an external HD).

Is it possible to install an app (Air or otherwise, since other apps put data in the user's library) so that it will exclusively use storage on an external HD? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: It usually doesn't help much to install an app onto an external HD if the data is stored in the $User folder. The only exception are some audio/video apps with extended libraries (e.g. sound files). So either outsource your user folder or the subfolder containing all additional data (e.g. move ~/Library/Preferences/Air/Some_data_folder to the external drive and relink it `ln -s  /Volumes/Data/Air/Some_data_folder ~/Library/Preferences/Air/Some_data_folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app doesn't let you configure where to store files, you can symlink the folder to your desired location.

1. Move the folder where the data is stored to the new location.
2. Run the following to symlink the folder:

   ```
   ln -s /Volumes/externalname/folder ~/Library/path/to/folder
   ```

You can move the application by itself, but that won't change where the app stores data files.

Comment: This solution is perfect, and really useful in many situations. Thanks!